# Multiple "in"s in a sentence

Tags: prepositions, writing-style, repetition

I always wonder whether the sentences which contain multiple *in*s are proper / a good practice. For example,

**Edit**
Ok. May be it was a bad example. Sorry about that. But it's a real question.

I meant to refer to spoken/written sentences which contain fragments like below (* is a noun phrase).

> in * in * in *

For ex. (Courtesy @fluently)

> I'll look at this issue **in** closer detail **in** 15 minutes **in** my bedroom **in** the other wing of the inn.

**before edit**

> He studies **in** the Stephen college **in** New City **in** Canada.

Doesn't it look odd? Any better alternatives?

Comment: He studies at Stephen College in New City, Canada. As for "practice", I think you're confusing what's valid grammatically with aesthetics. If something looks or sounds awkward, then try to rephrase it. A major goal of language is to communicate effectively, after all.

Comment: As @Zairja said, your question stems from a failure to use the correct grammar. Since it is effectively the case here, I suggest you to replace your example sentence with the following: "she has to come in in a certain way to home". Otherwise the question could be closed.

Comment: There are several ways of rearranging it to reduce the number of 'in's. For example "He studies in Canada at New City's Stephen College".

Comment: @Carlo_R.: is that what zairja said? I understood his/her comment to mean that it is certainly grammatical, but unpleasing.

Comment: I'll look at this issue in closer detail in 15 minutes in my bedroom in the other wing of the inn.

Comment: Oddly, none of the comments or the lone answer yet, covers the basic question -- is it **proper**? is it a good (an acceptable) **practice**. The OP never asked if the *in*s were grammatical, if they needed to be replaced or any other alternative to *in*.

Comment: The question as such is fine. The example is not. If a sentence does have several instances of the use of *in*, for whatever reason, the sentence does **not** become ungrammatical, improper or stylistically bad. @fluently was right. No one has taken note of his very useful comment, though.

Comment: @Carlo_R. I edited the question. But your example (two consecutive ins) wasn't what I had in mind.

Answer (score 2):

English does have its many flavours.

In your case, the sentence can be reworded depending if it is spoken or written. In a written piece, English seldom uses **in** when describing addresses. The sentence in written form can be reworded to

> He studies in the Stephen college, New City, Canada.

In spoken English, you can replace some occurences of *in* with other words such as *at*, *within* and so on. Replacing the *in*s with these words will make it less "awkward" and may probably pass along a clearer message.

Comment: However, this does not answer the basic question: If there are many *in* s, would that make it a wrong or bad sentence? I'm not down voting this yet.